# Using Google maps to control bicycle

Tags: ipad, google-maps, google-street-view, elevation

I would like to make a exercise bike like the "Tour de France bike from PRO-FORM with ifit"ut.

The bike is so bad I have decided to make a better one.

I could take it apart and use it for the new one.

PLS help me ...

- I will make everything myself.
- I have made a platform where I can put my pro outside bike and now sit inside in front of TV or iPad.
- For control elevation/braking force I need output data.
- For control speed and direction on Google Maps I need input data.

I just need to know what kind of data in/out I can get out of an iPad running Google Maps,
and where to get it ....

Henrik Simonsen
Denmark

Comment: Im not sure I understand you right but if you want some sort of navigation/realtime routing THEN as abhi says, google doesn't allow realtime navigation with their api AFAICS.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a custom iPad app that opens a HTTP listening port while the app is running, then probably install an arduino or something similar on the bike, which communicates with the iPad and the bike hardware.

You can use bluetooth or usb or wifi (perhaps wifi/ethernet) to communicate to your iPad app. There is a "camera connection kit" to give you a standard USB plug on the iPad, but wireless is easier. Some products also use the headphone jack (which does sound output and microphone input in one plug) to transfer data... that's the cheapest option but also the most difficult to implement.

I don't think you can use google maps, it would violate their EULA and they don't offer the kind of data you need.

What you should do instead is drive (or cycle) the course you want while recording the directions with a smartphone app like MotionX GPS, creating a gpx file(*) that your iPad/arduino can read.

(*) a gpx file is an industry standard XML format for defining a list of latitude/longitude/altitude positions.

You can probably also find gpx files that other cyclists have created and posted online. It's a common thing to share.